# Auto execute a python script from a Cygwin batch

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cygwin

A two-part problem I am having.
I am using ArcSight Console and need to pass variables from ArcSight to a python script. However, I don't have access to standalone Python, only a Cygwin client to run python.

Step 1) Launch Cygwin and automatically run the python script

My current Cygwin batch file is:

```
@echo off

c:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i
```

Step 2) Pass variables in the original command line to the python script for argv

```
python myscript var1 var2 var3
```

Am I taking the long way for this or am I attempting the impossible?

**Solution**

The batch file to launch cygwin now looks like this:

```
@echo off

c:
chdir c:\cygwin\bin

bash --login -i ./my_script.sh var1 var2 var3
```

my_script.sh is a bash script that passes the variables into python and launches the python script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my_var1 = '$1'" > vars.py
echo "my_var2 = '$2'" >> vars.py
echo "my_var3 = '$3'" >> vars.py
python my_python.py
```

Python script imports the variables from the vars.py:

```
import vars
print "Foo is %s" % (vars.my_var1)
```

A huge pain but this was the way it had to be done due to security restrictions on what our work machines can install. Wanted to leave this here in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.

Comment: I've currently done a very ad-hoc batch setup to get batch to do what I need done, but I would very much like to not use batch for this, as I can do a lot more with Python.

Comment: Came up with a solution, updated the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the solution in my initial question.